# How to make a D3 Line Chart Responsive

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to using D3 charts and am having an issue making my multi line chart responsive. I have reviewed some examples on how to make D3 responsive, but I can not make it work on my graph. If someone could assist me in making the code I currently have responsive I would really appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


   // Parse the date / time
   var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

   // Set the ranges
   var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
   var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

   // Define the axes
   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
   .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
   .orient("left").ticks(8);

   // Define the line
   var valueline = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.average_ticnum); });

   var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.average_fatiguenum); });

   var valueline3 = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.average_stressnum); });

   var valueline4 = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_sugars); });

   var valueline5 = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_total_carbohydrate); });

   // Adds the svg canvas
   var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", 
     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



   // Get the data
   d3.json("progress_output.php?useremail=<?php echo $useremail; ?>",                              function(error, data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.average_ticnum = +d.average_ticnum;
    d.fatiguenum = +d.average_fatiguenum;
    d.stressnum = +d.average_stressnum;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0,12]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#891f83")
.attr("id","ticLine")
.attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#7db6e3")
.attr("id","fatigueLine")
.attr("d", valueline2(data));

svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#36376a")
.attr("id","stressLine")
.attr("d", valueline3(data));

svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#9bcf81")
.attr("id","sugarLine")
.attr("d", valueline4(data));

svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#efa465")
.attr("id","carbLine")
.attr("d", valueline5(data));

// Add the Dots
svg.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("id","ticDots")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#891f83")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_ticnum); });

svg.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#7db6e3")
.attr("id","fatigueDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_fatiguenum); });

svg.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#36376a")
.attr("id", "stressDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_stressnum); });

svg.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("id","sugarDots")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#9bcf81")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_sugars); });

svg.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#efa465")
.attr("id","carbDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_total_carbohydrate); });


// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);

//Add the Tic title
svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 15)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("id", "ticText")
.style("color", "#891f83")
.style("fill", "#891f83") 
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")        
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = ticLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        width = 200;
        height = 200;
        d3.select("#ticLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#ticDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);

        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        ticLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Tic Severity");

//Add the fatigue title
svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 115)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#7bd6e3")
.style("fill", "#7bd6e3")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = fatigueLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#fatigueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#fatigueDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        fatigueLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Fatigue");


//Add the Stress title
svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 190)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#36376a")
.style("fill", "#36376a")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = stressLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#stressLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#stressDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        stressLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Stress");

//Add the sugar title
svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 250)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#9bcf81")
.style("fill", "#9bcf81")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = sugarLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#sugarLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#sugarDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        sugarLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Sugars");

//Add the carb title
svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 320)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#efa465")
.style("fill", "#efa465")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = carbLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#carbLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#carbDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        carbLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Carbohydrates");
 });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a granular question and consists of many sub-questions but I will do my best to be helpful.

First off, change to:

```
function resize() {
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

   // rest of your code here
}
```

Then call the function when window is resized:

```
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
```

remember that you need to redraw the chart on resizeNow you got new rendered based on the new heights you received. There are many more improvements you can make: scaling ticks, fonts and etc. Have a look at this example, it's very thorough: [Building Responsive Visualizations with D3.js](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/)